# Angular. How to switch component depending on service's actions

Tags: javascript, angular

Lets say I have 2 components, `aComponent` and `bComponent`. I have them redered inside the `AppComponent`

```html
<app-a>
<app-b>
```

And I have service `myService` that has method `.trigger()`.

What I want is to show only `aComponent`, but whenever I call `myService.trigger()` from another part of code, it would switch and show `bComponent`. That's perfect implementation that I can't reach.

**Question is:** Is it possible to do so? And if not what is the best closest solution.

The only working solution I got:

I added `.trigger()` inside `AppComponent`

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'spa';
  show: boolean = false;
  trigger() {
    this.show = true;
  }
}
```

And rendered components like so:

```html
<div *ngIf="!show; else show">
  <app-a></app-a>
</div>

<ng-template #show>
  <app-b></app-b>
</ng-template>
```

Then whenever I want to trigger switching, I add instance of the app to the constructor and call it's method:

```js
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private app: AppComponent
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.app.trigger();
  }
}
```

Even though it's working pretty good, I myself see that it's a dirty solution. **Components** are not intended to be used inside another components, but **Services** are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Subject` from `rxjs` library for that.

In your service file:

```
// a-service.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    trigger(state: boolean) {
        this.subject.next(state);
    }

    getTrigger(): Subject<any> {
        return this.subject;
    }
}
```

and in your `AppComponent`:

```
// app.component.ts
...
private show = false;

constructor (private aService: AService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.aService.getTrigger().subscribe(state => {
        this.show = state;
    });
}
```

the template can be as you provided - it's fine:

```
<div *ngIf="!show; else show">
  <app-a></app-a>
</div>

<ng-template #show>
  <app-b></app-b>
</ng-template>
```

And if you want to trigger from another component, you do it like this:

```
// another.component.ts
...    
constructor (private aService: AService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.aService.trigger(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Guys, you are the best! Answer in 30 minutes, this is incredible.. Everything is working properly and the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to communicate between different components and services which aren't directly related, is via 'Subjects'.

You can try to create a subject and pass in values to it from `myService.trigger()`. And you can subscribe to that `subject` from whichever component you want to access that trigger data.